# On convergent series - in the spirit of Abel and Dini

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Nonexistence of boundary between convergent and divergent series?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49415/nonexistence-of-boundary-between-convergent-and-divergent-series)

I'm hoping the following is true:

> Suppose $a_i $ is a positive sequence and $\sum_i a_i < \infty.$ Then there exists a positive sequence $b_i$ s.t $\sum_i b_i < \infty$ and $\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} < \infty$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not correct. Take $a_n=1/n^2$.

Let us show that $b_n$ with
required properties does not exist. Consider the set 
$$E=\{ n: b_n\geq 1/n\}.$$
As $\sum b_n<\infty$, we have $$\sum_E1/n<\infty.$$
Now on $N\backslash E$ we have $b_n<1/n,$ so $1/b_n>n$ and as $\sum a_n/b_n<\infty$,
we conclude that $$\sum_{N\backslash E}1/n<\infty.$$
adding the last two inequalities we obtain a contradiction.